# Text to Image generation using torch model/path file

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, computer-vision, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I trained a text to image generation model based on https://github.com/aelnouby/Text-to-Image-Synthesis. Now I have 2 path files (one for generator , another for discriminator) . How to generate images using this path files?

Comment: This line https://github.com/aelnouby/Text-to-Image-Synthesis/blob/master/trainer.py#L420 looks like a good starting point

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen : I made a mistake by not passing my path files. Corrected it and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your generator path file here.  self.generator.load_state_dict(torch.load(pre_trained_gen))
Refer line 28 of trainer.py